# inconvertible types; cannot cast android.support.v4.app.fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm following the Google Maps documentation and I'm getting this error. I just want to know what am I doing worng

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

This is the error

> 'inconvertible types cannot cast android.support.v4.app.fragment'

I'm getting this error as soon as the `Google Maps Activity` is created by default. Have spent 3 days working on it but still not able to find any solution to this petty problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the new [Google Play services `play-services-maps:17.0.0`](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_17_2019):

Google Maps from version `17.0.0` has switched to AndroidX. Which means `SupportMapFragment` now extends [`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html), not the Support Library equivalent.

> **Warning**: This release is a MAJOR version update and breaking change.
>
> - Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

You need to either switch back to `16.1.0` or migrate your app to AndroidX.